# How to prevent SQL Server bug in inner select expression (using 'IN' & 'EXISTS' keywords)

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax-error, sql-in

I have two different tables with their different columns as below:

```
CREATE TABLE T1(C1 INT)
CREATE TABLE T2(C2 INT)
```

Every programmer knows if we write a query with wrong syntax, query compiler should give us an error. Such as this one:

```
SELECT C1 FROM T2 
--ERROR: Invalid column name 'C1'.
```

But if we use this wrong query as inner select, unfortunately SQL will execute it:

```
SELECT * 
FROM T1
WHERE C1 IN (SELECT C1 FROM T2) 
--returns all rows of T1
```

And also the following wrong query will execute too and returns all rows of `T1`

```
SELECT * 
FROM T1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT C1 FROM T2) 
--returns all rows of T1
```

It gets worse when we use these wrong queries in `UPDATE` such as:

```
UPDATE T1
SET C1 = NULL
WHERE C1 IN (SELECT C1 FROM T2) 
--updates all rows of T1
```

Now, I want to prevent this bug. I can force my DB developers to be careful but is there any systematic way to prevent this bug?

Comment: Always use a two part name - `Table.Column`.

Comment: Just to be clear, this is not a SQL Server bug, The examples are a bug in the application query. Ambiguous column names are resolved the innermost scope. The best practice in multi-table queries is to qualify columns with the table name or alias to avoid surprises and improve maintainability.

Comment: You can prevent updates via trigger

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ever heard of [`Correlated Subquery`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187638(v=sql.105).aspx), you can always refer outer query columns inside the subquery

am sure you must have seen queries like this

```
SELECT * FROM T1 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM T2 where t1.c1 = t2.c2)
```

here `C1` column from `T1` is referred in `Where` clause, you are referring in `Select` thats the difference. There is no BUG here

Comment: Yes, this is quite common and useful.

Comment: From the documentation: `In queries that include a correlated subquery (also known as a repeating subquery), the subquery depends on the outer query for its values. This means that the subquery is executed repeatedly, once for each row that might be selected by the outer query`.  Which means this might execute quite poorly in some cases (although I'm inclined to believe the optimizer is going to Do Something About It).

Comment: I'd imagine most enterprise grade databases will be able to rewrite a typical correlated subquery so that the query is executed only once.. if it makes you feel happier though, there's usually little harm in taking the correlated query and inner joining it as a subquery in the join area. Profiling the two will tell you whether your database successfully rewrote it

Answer (score 5):

> Is there any systematic way to prevent this bug?

Always use two-part names - `[Table].[Column]`.